# Issues with setting a global setting in PostgreSQL 9.5/PostGIS2.2

Tags: postgis, postgresql-9.5, alter-database

I am trying to set a global setting/GUC variable `postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers` from the `PostGIS` extension for a while. I am a non-admin user but can ask admin to change settings if needed. But I tried several different methods following the instructions but none worked.

1. I tried the old fashion way to change environmental variables. I had the following added to `/etc/environment`:

   ```
   POSTGIS_ENABLE_OUTDB_RASTERS=1
   POSTGIS_GDAL_ENABLED_DRIVERS=ENABLE_ALL
   ```

so that `echo $POSTGIS_GDAL_ENABLED_DRIVERS` returns `ENABLE_ALL`

Now, in my non-admin PostreSQL account,

```
SELECT short_name, long_name FROM ST_GdalDrivers();
```

returns `0 rows`, meaning no GDAL drivers are enabled.

2. I also tried to have postgres to:

   ```
   ALTER SYSTEM SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers TO 'ENABLE_ALL';
   ```

but I got an error:

```
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers"
```

3. I tried to:

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE my_db SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers TO 'ENABLE_ALL';
   ```

but I got:

```
ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers"
```

In sum, I can ask admin to change some settings **once** as in methods 1 and 2, but not every time e.g. when I do a full database restore (method 3).

My question is:

**How can I make the above methods work?**

FYI, my PostgreSQL version is 9.5.1, OS is Lubuntu 16.04 beta

```
    postgis_version            
---------------------------------------
 2.2 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
```

In method 3, I can use `postgres` to `ALTER DATABASE` but I can't ask amin to do that every time I restore db, where I do something like:

```
dropdb my_db && createdb -T template my_db $$ psql < my_pg_dump_file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the `/etc/postgresql/9.x/main/environment` file and set following environment variables `POSTGIS_GDAL_ENABLED_DRIVERS=ENABLE_ALL` `POSTGIS_ENABLE_OUTDB_RASTERS=1`. Restart then the server.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging first, do this.

1. `SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers = 'ENABLE_ALL';`
2. `SELECT * FROM ST_GdalDrivers();`

If this returns nothing, you've got larger issues. Did you install from the Ubuntu/LUbuntu repos? Or, did you build yourself?

[`ALTER SYSTEM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersystem.html) is the new method to alter the configuration file with a pseudo-sql command. If you're seeing this

> ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers"

That means that you do not have that option in your `postgresql.conf`. (perhaps it's commented out.) That however you can still add it the conf file manually.

> A configuration option to set the enabled GDAL drivers in the PostGIS environment. Affects the GDAL configuration variable GDAL_SKIP. **This option can be set in PostgreSQL's configuration file: postgresql.conf.** It can also be set by connection or transaction.

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers TO 'GTiff PNG JPEG';
```

or to whatever you want. I would **not set the environment**. Instead, just put this in your `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf`

```
postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers = 'ENABLE_ALL';
```

Which is essentially the same as what [the docs say](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_gdal_enabled_drivers.html),

```
SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers = 'ENABLE_ALL';
```